# Error while creating dynamic cloud config using actuator

Tags: spring-boot, cloud, microservices, spring-boot-actuator

The controller is InfyGo_Booking to which @RefreshScope is added and also added required dependencies in pom.xml. I have also exposed the endpoints in bootstrap.properties. But still https://localhost:9000/actuator/refresh is giving me 404 error. Can you help me pointing out if I am missing something?

Controller:

```
    @RestController
    @RefreshScope
    @RequestMapping("/book")
    public class BookingController {
    
        protected Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(BookingController.class.getName());
        @Autowired
        private TicketService ticketService;
        @Autowired
        private PassengerService passengerService;
        
        private Ticket ticket;
        private int noOfSeats;
        ClientHttpRequestFactory requestFactory = new     
                  HttpComponentsClientHttpRequestFactory(HttpClients.createDefault());
    
            RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate(requestFactory);
    //      
    
        public BookingController() {
            ticket = new Ticket();      
        }
    
    
        @PostMapping(value = "/{flightId}/{username}", produces = "application/json", consumes = "application/json")
        public ResponseEntity<BookingDetails> bookFlight(@PathVariable("flightId") String flightId,
             @Valid @RequestBody PassengerDetails passengerDetails, @PathVariable("username") String username,Errors errors) throws InfyGoServiceException, ARSServiceException {
                
                if (errors.hasErrors()) {
                return new ResponseEntity(new ClientErrorInformation(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST.value(),errors.getFieldError("passengerList").getDefaultMessage()), HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
                }
            if(passengerDetails.getPassengerList().isEmpty())
                throw new InfyGoServiceException(ExceptionConstants.PASSENGER_LIST_EMPTY.toString());
                
            List<Passenger> passengerList = new ArrayList<Passenger>();
            for (Passenger passengers : passengerDetails.getPassengerList()) {
                passengerList.add(passengers);
                
    
            }
            System.out.println(passengerList.toString());
    
            logger.log(Level.INFO, "Book Flight method ");
    
            logger.log(Level.INFO, passengerDetails.toString());
            int pnr = (int) (Math.random() * 1858955);
            
            ticket.setPnr(pnr);
    //      Date date = new Date();
    //      Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    //      calendar.setTime(date);
             
             
            Flight flightDto= restTemplate.getForObject("http://localhost:9004/flights/"+flightId, Flight.class);
    
            double fare= flightDto.getFare();
            System.out.println("Fare per person:****** " + fare);
            System.out.println("List size:****** " + passengerDetails.getPassengerList().size());
            double totalFare = fare * (passengerDetails.getPassengerList().size());
    
            BookingDetails bookingDetails = new BookingDetails();
            bookingDetails.setPassengerList(passengerDetails.getPassengerList());
            bookingDetails.setPnr(pnr);
            bookingDetails.setTotalFare(totalFare);
            ticket.setBookingDate(new Date());
            System.out.println(ticket.getBookingDate());
            ticket.setDepartureDate(flightDto.getFlightAvailableDate());
            ticket.setDepartureTime(flightDto.getDepartureTime());
            ticket.setFlightId(flightDto.getFlightId());
            ticket.setUserId(username);     
            ticket.setTotalFare(totalFare);
            noOfSeats = passengerDetails.getPassengerList().size();
            ticket.setNoOfSeats(noOfSeats);
            ticketService.createTicket(ticket);
        
            addPassengers(bookingDetails.getPassengerList());
            
             restTemplate.postForEntity("http://localhost:9004/flights/"+flightId+"/"+noOfSeats,null,null);
    
            return new ResponseEntity<BookingDetails>(bookingDetails, HttpStatus.OK);
    
        }
    
        private void addPassengers(List<Passenger> passengers) {
            
            for (Passenger passenger : passengers) {
                passenger.setTicket(ticket);        
    
            }
    
            passengerService.createPassenger(passengers);
    
        }
    
    }
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
  </parent>
  <groupId>com.example</groupId>
  <artifactId>demo</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>demo</name>
  <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
  <properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR5</spring-cloud.version>
  </properties>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-config</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
</dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
            <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-activemq</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/javax.validation/validation-api -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
    <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
    
</dependency>
    
    <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-cache</artifactId>
   </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-redis</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.12</version>
</dependency>
   <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <exclusions>
        <exclusion>
          <groupId>org.junit.vintage</groupId>
          <artifactId>junit-vintage-engine</artifactId>
        </exclusion>
      </exclusions>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>
  <dependencyManagement>
    <dependencies>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
        <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
        <type>pom</type>
        <scope>import</scope>
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>
    </dependencies>
  </dependencyManagement>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
</project>
```

bootstrap.properties:

```
spring.cloud.config.uri=http://localhost:1111
management.endpoints.web.exposure.include=*
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are trying to call the actuator as a URL from browser which by default uses GET method . Please try the same URL and hit a post request using any app , you must see a success response .